# Identification and connected components

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification, connectedness

**Proposition**: Let $f: X \to Y$ be a quotient map. If the connected components of $X$ are open, then also the connected components of $Y$ are open.

**Proof**:

Let $y \in Y$ and let $C_y$ be the connected component of $Y$ containing $y$. I want to show that $C_y$ is open. Since $f$ is a quotient map, it will follow from the fact that $f^{-1}(C_y)$ is open.

I want to show that $f^{-1}(C_y) = \bigcup\{C_x \mid x \in A\}$ for some $A \subseteq X$. From this we will have that $f^{-1}(C_y)$ is open being union of open sets.

Let $x \in f^{-1}(C_y)$, then $\exists \, z \in C_y$ s.t. $f(x)=z$ and $C_z=C_y$. Clearly $z=f(x) \in f(C_x)$ and $f(C_x)$ is connected. Then $f(C_x) \subseteq C_z=C_y$, and then $C_x \subseteq f^{-1}(C_y)$.

**Doubts**

1. Is my proof correct?
2. I was wondering if $A=f^{-1}(y)$ but I'm not really sure about that...

Comment: Minor comment: the standard term in topology for what you call an "identification" is a "quotient map".

Comment: Could you explain your second question a bit more?

Comment: @Lee Mosher Thank you, I wasn't sure about the english term. Fixed!

Comment: Your proof looks correct to me. And what it shows is that you can take $A = f^{-1}(C_y)$.

Comment: @TPace I was wondering if the counter image of the connected component of $y$ is the union of the connected component of the points $x \in X$, s.t. $y=f(x)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said in my comment, your proof shows that you can take $A = f^{-1}(C_y)$.

But it's not generally true that you can take $A = f^{-1}(y)$. For example, let 
$$X = [-2,-1) \cup [0,+1]
$$
and let
$$Y = [0,+1]
$$
and let $f : X \to Y$ be the quotient map 
$$f(x) = \begin{cases}
x+2 & \quad\text{if $x \in [-2,-1)$} \\
x & \quad\text{if $x \in [0,+1]$}
\end{cases}
$$
For $y=1 \in Y$, taking $A = f^{-1}(y) = \{1\} \subset X$ will not work.